# Using the Induction Hypothesis in Inequality Proofs

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

I am tasked with proving the following inequality using mathematical induction:
 $$(1) \quad P(n):{ 4n }^{ 2 }+12n+7<100n^{2},\quad n>2$$

What I am not sure about is whether my use of the induction hypothesis (IH) is correct and whether I use it at all. Here is my proof:

$$(2)\quad { P(b):4\cdot1 }^{ 2 }+12\cdot 1+7<100\cdot 1^{ 2 }, \quad b=1$$
$$(3) \quad 23<100$$

Since P(b) is true for b = 1, we can move on to the inductive step. Assume the following is true for some k =< n (this is the inductive hypothesis):

$$(4)\quad P(k):{ 4k }^{ 2 }+12k+7<100k^{2}$$

We must prove that P(k+1) is true:

$$(5) \quad P(k+1):{ 4(k+1) }^{ 2 }+12(k+1)+7<100(k+1)^{2}$$

We make the expression have a form that resembles inequality (4):

$$(6) \quad 4({k}^2+2k+1)+12k+12+7<100(k^{2}+2k+1)$$
$$(7) \quad \underline{4{k}^2}+8k+4+\underline{12k}+12+\underline{7}<\underline{100k^{2}}+200k+100$$

Now that the form resembles (4) we use the IH to remove these elements from the inequality (they are underlined for readability in 7)). By the IH:

$$(8) \quad 8k+4+12\overset{IH}{<}200k+100$$
$$(9) \quad 8k+16<200k+100$$

We see that (9) is trivially true. Thus P(k+1) has been proved. By the principle of mathematical induction P(n) is also true.

Do I use the IH correctly? Is the proof valid?

Comment: on my mind from (6) better make this 
$4k^2+8k+4+12k+12+7 \overset{IH}{<} 100k^2+8k+16 < 100k^2+200k+100=100(k+1)^2$

Comment: Or just argue that $4n^2+12n+7< 4n^2 + 12n^2 + n^2 = 17n^2 < 100n^2$.

Comment: I agree. Using induction for this inequality is missleading. You should not always use induction, just because you have naturel numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is valid, though the writing is a bit unclear (to me at least). (For example, I don't know what you mean by claiming that $(8)$ depends on the IH.) In general it's clearest to write proofs starting from known facts and hypotheses and proceeding to implications, rather than the other way around. Here, the things we know or can assume are $(9)$ and $(4)$, and we want to prove $(5)$, so we want to show a chain of implications starting from $(9)$ and $(4)$ and proceeding eventually to $(5)$. I would suggest reordering your proof of the inductive step as follows (though it's certainly not the only way):

$(9)$ is trivially true

$(8)$ follows from $(9)$

$(4)$ is true -- this is the inductive hypothesis

$(7)$ is true by adding $(4)$ and $(8)$

$(6)$ is a reformulation of $(7)$

$(5)$ is a reformulation of $(6)$, and $(5)$ is what we set out to prove in the inductive step.

(Note that this organization makes it clear that the IH is used in deriving $(7)$, $(6)$, and $(5)$, but $(8)$ does not depend on the IH.)

Comment: I see your point and thank you for the answer! But I did not know (9) until I concluded the proof? I mean, it would be very hard for me to have the foresight to know that that particular inequality would eventually result in (5). Then I think it is more natural to go the other way around? Would you say then that (7) is dependent on the IH? But overall the proof is correct but unclear?

Comment: @emba Very often the process of discovering a proof differs from how it is written. Your goal in writing a proof is not to demonstrate how you discovered it, rather to convince someone else of the truth of a proposition. When you put $(9)$ first, I (reader of the proof) know that $(9)$ is true, even if I don't know yet why it is relevant. (Imagine you're telling me, "You agree that $(9)$ is true, right? Well $(9)$ implies $(5)$, so you have to agree that $(5)$ is true, too!")

Comment: @emba Yes, I would say that $(7)$ is dependent on the IH. And yes, overall the proof is correct, though I'd probably say certain statements contained in the proof (e.g., your claim that $(8)$ that dependent on the IH) are inaccurate.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insightful comments!

Answer (score 1):

No, your proof is invalid. The problem is that you’re trying to go from $a<b$ and $a+c<b+d$ to $c<d$ by subtracting $a$ from one side and $b$ from the other. This is invalid, as can be seen from the example of $10+2<12+1$.

Comment: See my answer -- my interpretation of the idea of this proof is that it does go from $a < b$ and $c < d$ to $a+c < b+d$, but it's written backwards so it looks like what you're describing.